# Is there a way to 'pretty' print MongoDB shell output to a file?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

Specifically, I want to print the results of a mongodb `find()` to a file. The JSON object is too large so I'm unable to view the entire object with the shell window size.

Comment: Came here through search years later:
The mongo shell output is not a valid json but some JavaScript.
Look at the output of Object IDs and Dates as a function call to 'ObejctId()` and 'ISODate()'. And there will be "NaN"s, not "null"s. 
A bit anoying, so some regex is still needed to get a json that can be used with e.g. jq

Answer (score 234, accepted):

The shell provides some nice but hidden features because it's an interactive environment.

When you run commands from a javascript file via mongo commands.js you won't get quite identical behavior.

There are two ways around this.

(1) fake out the shell and make it think you are in interactive mode

```
$ mongo dbname << EOF > output.json
db.collection.find().pretty()
EOF
```

or
(2) use Javascript to translate the result of a `find()` into a printable JSON

```
mongo dbname command.js > output.json
```

where command.js contains this (or its equivalent):

```
printjson( db.collection.find().toArray() )
```

This will pretty print the array of results, including `[ ]` - if you don't want that you can iterate over the array and `printjson()` each element.

By the way if you are running just a single Javascript statement you don't have to put it in a file and instead you can use:

```
$ mongo --quiet dbname --eval 'printjson(db.collection.find().toArray())' > output.json
```

Comment: command.js has to be a readable file that exists in your current directory and which has the javascript you want to run.

Comment: How do I do it for a remote mongo db? I tried `mongo blah.mongolab.com:33478/blah -u user -p pass --eval "my query" >> dump.txt` but it gave me `JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

Comment: that error means what's inside your quotes after --eval is not legal syntax.  I recommend using single quotes outside whole expressions and if you have need for quotes inside of it use double quotes for that.

Comment: Option 2 is really the only option if you have more than a handful of results, since in option 1 it'll just stop at 'Type "it" for more'.

Comment: not really @Tomty - the size of shell batch is controllable with a variable inside the shell. you can put DBQuery.shellBatchSize=10000 into your .mongodbrc.js file and it will "stop" after 10000 results instead of 20.

Comment: Of course you can @AsyaKamsky, but A) That's not mentioned anywhere in the answer. B) That's still limited. C) Why would you? Stuff like that happens because the shell is meant to be interactive, and "faking it out" seems unnecessary.

Comment: I agree that faking it out is "wrong" but it is possible.  but that's why I gave the "real" answer that doesn't require faking.

Comment: Excellent! We should run it before go to mongo.

Comment: is there anyway to access these features when running mogosh wthin compasss?

Answer (score 31):

Since you are doing this on a terminal and just want to inspect a record in a sane way, you can use a trick like this:

```
mongo | tee somefile
```

Use the session as normal - `db.collection.find().pretty()` or whatever you need to do, ignore the long output, and exit.  A transcript of your session will be in the file `tee` wrote to.

Be mindful that the output might contain escape sequences and other garbage due to the mongo shell expecting an interactive session.  `less` handles these gracefully.

Answer (score 13):

Just put the commands you want to run into a file, then pass it to the shell along with the database name and redirect the output to a file.  So, if your find command is in `find.js` and your database is `foo`, it would look like this:

```
./mongo foo find.js >> out.json
```

Comment: This did not work for me, only printed out shell version and db name to `out.json`. `mongo foo < find.js > out.json` did work.

Comment: this answer was written before the tools were rewritten in Go and many versions ago, unless you are using something very old, then that's probably why it's not working for you

Answer (score 12):

Put your query (e.g. `db.someCollection.find().pretty()`) to a javascript file, let's say `query.js`. Then run it in your operating system's shell using command:

`mongo yourDb < query.js > outputFile`

Query result will be in the file named 'outputFile'.

By default Mongo prints out first 20 documents IIRC. If you want more you can define new value to batch size in Mongo shell, e.g.

`DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 100`.

Comment: This. Don't be misdirected by `.js` extension. You can write all those nice mongo shell queries without changing them at all.

Answer (score 7):

Using `print` and `JSON.stringify` you can simply produce a **valid** `JSON` result.
Use `--quiet` flag to filter shell noise from the output.
Use `--norc` flag to avoid `.mongorc.js` evaluation. (I had to do it because of  a pretty-formatter that I use, which produces *invalid JSON* output)
Use `DBQuery.shellBatchSize = ?` replacing `?` with the limit of the actual result to avoid paging.

And finally, use `tee` to pipe the terminal output to a file:

```
// Shell:
mongo --quiet --norc ./query.js | tee ~/my_output.json

// query.js:
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 2000;
function toPrint(data) {
  print(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}

toPrint(
  db.getCollection('myCollection').find().toArray()
);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I managed to save result with **writeFile()** function.

```
> writeFile("/home/pahan/output.txt", tojson(db.myCollection.find().toArray()))
```

Mongo shell version was 4.0.9

Answer (score 5):

In the new **mongodb shell 5.0+** [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/), it integrate the [Node.js fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), so you can **simply** do below in the new [mongosh](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/) shell for pretty print the output:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(db.test.find().toArray(), null, 2))
```

Without any problems such as the `ObjectId` has been stripped, etc., which is better than the `printjson` or `.pretty()`.

The above code can work as the description denotes:

> The MongoDB Shell, mongosh, is a **fully functional JavaScript and Node.js 14.x REPL** environment for interacting with MongoDB deployments. You can use the MongoDB Shell to test queries and operations directly with your database.

The old `mongo` shell also marked as *Legacy*, so you should move to this new way.

Answer (score 2):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13111118/6053299) from Asya Kamsky, I wrote a one-line bat script for Windows. The line looks like this:

`mongo --quiet %1 --eval "printjson(db.%2.find().toArray())" > output.json`

Then one can run it:

`exportToJson.bat DbName CollectionName`

Answer (score 1):

Also there is [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport) for that, but I'm not sure since which version it is available.

Example:

```
mongoexport -d dbname -c collection --jsonArray --pretty --quiet --out output.json
```

Answer (score 1):

As [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47451080/7567116) by Neodan mongoexport is quite useful with `-q` option for query. It also convert `ObjectId` to standard format of JSON `"$oid"`. E.g:

```
mongoexport -d yourdb -c yourcol --jsonArray --pretty -q '{"field": "filter value"}' -o output.json
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command to acheive it:

`mongo admin -u <userName> -p <password> --quiet --eval "cursor = rs.status(); printjson(cursor)" > output.json`