# How to scroll to the beginning of a big document in MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents containing lists of up to hundred comments in MongoDB. When running findOne() in mongo shell in Windows 7, I can see only the ending of the document. If I try to scroll to the beginning, the scroll stops without reaching the start of the document.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/378313/windows-command-prompt-how-do-i-increase-my-buffer

Comment: I have tested the recomendations described in this answer and they do not work in mongo shell. The buffer size increase up to 999 stlll does not reach the begining of the document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104800/printing-mongodb-shell-output-to-file

Comment: If the only solution is to save the document to the file then the recommendations can be applied.