# how to do mongo export to json without type

Tags: mongodb, google-bigquery

My high level purpose is to export mongo data to Bigquery so I could do data analysis.

I don't want to export as csv because doing so requires me to specify fields to export manually.

However, `mongoexport` to `json` will have these `type` data like

```
"registerTimestamp":{"$numberLong":"1429594506335"}
```

This tpye `$numberLong` really messes up my bigquery import. Error message like:

> Errors:
>   query: Illegal field name: $numberLong

I don't find a way to export mongo without type. How to solve this export to bigquery problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up exporting CSV and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like this:

Create a script call command.js containing:

```
printjson( db.collection.find().toArray() )
```

Then execute the command as below:

```
mongo dbname command.js > output.json
```

[This article is the source and will provide more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104800/printing-mongodb-shell-output-to-file#13111118)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could open the json file with vim then replace the type with an empty string using a regular expression like this:

1. to NumberLong(***), use

> **:%s/NumberLong((.*))/\1/g**

2. to ObjectId(***), use

> **:%s/NumberLong((.*))/\1/g**

Comment: Seems to be twice the same regex.