# MongoDB find() output to file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to write the output of a MongoDB find() query to a file just by simply using a Linux shell command or running a script?

Right now I have to manually type in step-by-step. Example:

```sh
$ mongo
> use owndb
> db.CollectionName.find(<query>) ### and then copy and paste the result on a text editor
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to 'pretty' print MongoDB shell output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104800/is-there-a-way-to-pretty-print-mongodb-shell-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this:

```
mongo --quiet dbname  --eval 'printjson(db.collection.find().toArray())' > output.json
```

Comment: Also it is a more like as workaround than a solution. For this task exists `mongoexport`.

Comment: Thank for your comment @Neodan. I search find this suitable for this question however did I violate SO rules ? I will delete this answer If It doesn't commit standard rules for stack overflow member

Comment: Always is better to mark post as duplicate, than duplicate an answer (-;

Answer (score 5):

You can use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport) for that.

Example:

```
mongoexport -d dbname -c collection --jsonArray --pretty --quiet --out output.json
```

Comment: I often think about mongoexport when I need to export whole db or a collections. However, with this answer I also find that mongoexport has option --query for query too. So It may be better than my answer

Comment: For export of whole db or collection is better to use mongodump (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

Comment: Yes I appreciate your comment

Comment: Perhaps I may need to modify my question because I did not specify whether I am exporting the collection or not. The example I gave suggested I am intending to export the whole collection but I do occasionally need to produce an output file based on a query. Appreciated all the discussions and explanations with thanks.

Comment: @theciezac `mongoexport` have `--query` (or `-q`) for that ;-)