# MongoDB JS ignoring underscore

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have date in mongo in below format

```
_id: 10_-0043_-00
```

My JS file is :--

```
use test
db.getCollection('test').find({_id : "10_-0043_-00"},{ _id  : 1})
```

I am running the query using unix box as below :--

```
mongo localhost:27048/test -u user -p mongo123 < mongo.js > mongo.txt
```

But when I check the output it is coming as

```
 10-0043-00
```

Similar is case when I am having \ or = or "

```
145678-TEST-23" becomes 145678-TEST-23\  , ABC100-10TEST\B becomes ABC100-10TEST\\B
```

Any idea to get this fixed ?

Regards

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4431

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104800/is-there-a-way-to-pretty-print-mongodb-shell-output-to-a-file/13111118